# How to call Web Api method that

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am writing a Web API method to export a PDF file from querying data from database.

I am able to get this worked by calling directly and get the result as expected. But calling this method from angularjs is not working. I see that the method is called but download is not happenning. I saw in someposts that ajax calls dont work on downloading the content....if so what are the other options to call this method and get the file downloaded ? Can somebody give some hint on how to get this worked ?

This is the code I wrote on WEB API and angularjs.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("ExportAppsData")]
public HttpResponseMessage ExportAppsData(string ids, bool skip)
{
    Int64[] convertedIds = new Int64[] { };
    if (ids != null)
        convertedIds = ids.Split(',').Select(n => Convert.ToInt64(n)).ToArray();
        List<App> apps = new List<App>();
        if (skip)
            apps = _appRepository.GetAllApps().SkipWhile(a => convertedIds.Contains(a.Id)).ToList();
        else
            apps = _appRepository.GetAllApps().Where(a => convertedIds.Contains(a.Id)).ToList();
        List<AppDto> mappedResult = _mapppingEngine.Map<List<App>, List<AppDto>>(apps);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, mappedResult,new PdfMediaTypeFormatter());
}

function exportAppsData(appIds, skipFlag) {
        return $http(
            {
                url: ngSettings.apiServiceUri + 'api/Apps/ExportAppsData',
                responseType : ArrayBuffer,
                params: { ids: appIds.join(","), skip: skipFlag },
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                headers: {
                    Accept: "text/csv; charset=utf-8",
                },
            method: "GET",
            }
            );
    }
```

Comment: Construct a link, do a standard GET with anchor tag (not intercepted by Angular). You can also cause the anchor to open popup page to download.

Comment: Constructing a link with angular variables seems to work provided I dont have [Authorize] on the web api method. Otherwise I am getting an error "Authorization has been denied for this request".

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `Accept` header to `application/pdf` instead of `text/csv; charset=utf-8`.